# Speeding up Python Imports

Tags: python, import

I have a large program that is structured using object oriented techniques, and I have one main driver module that imports a bunch of other classes, which they in turn import more python built-in modules or other classes.  All together I would say there is well over 250 
`from x import y statements` (I don't have control over this part of the code), some are duplicates in other classes and some are unique.  I profiled my code and as I suspected the majority of the time is in the start up with import so many modules and classes.  There is a way to speed up this?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean when you say "structured using object oriented techniques" - as this is raising some flags that it might be the cause of your frustration.

Comment: OO as in I have module X that imports a bunch of things and defines class x, then another module Y that imports a bunch of things and defines class y, and a much more with some inheriting from others.  Then I have a driver module that imports class x,y,.... and uses them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can move the import statements to inside your functions to reduce initial startup.](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Import_Statement_Overhead)

Another technique would be to copy your modules to a ramdisk or tmpfs for faster IO (these use RAM, which runs much faster).

Comment: Is it possible to copy they pyc to ramdisk and import them for faster use since they are already compiled?

Comment: You can put them anywhere you want, but I/O is unlikely to be the bottleneck.